# Как узнать под какой мандатной меткой выполняется запрос к PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, astra-linux

Мне необходимо в своей функции на PostgreSQL по разному обрабатывать данные полученные под разными мандатными метками. Но не могу найти, есть ли возможность из под постреса получить мандатную метку из под которой выполняется запрос к моей функции?

Comment: У Вас обычный постгрес или генно-модифицированный создателями астры?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а да. Пожалуй это важно, это постгрес из дистрибутива Астры

Comment: я правильно понимаю что Вы хотите внутри встроенной процедуры узнать macid юзера который сделал запрос по сети?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ скорее всего да. Потому что по факту будет обращаться сервис на c++ к этой функции. Вероятно он будет прокидывать метку пользователя до базы. Я в этом контексте не силен.

Comment: насколько я все это понимаю - метка прокидывается на уровне tcp соединения, если этот сервис запущен на той же машине что и бд и это сервис инициирует запросы к бд, то внутри постгеса вы узнаете мак метку этого сервииса..

Comment: По логи да, она должна прокинуться. Но вопрос собственно в том, как ее узнать? Чтобы можно было в CASE обработать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял свою ошибку, что искал ответ не в той документации. Нашел решение:

```
SELECT current_setting('ac_session_maclabel')::maclabel;
```